# How to edit user Common.css file

Tags: css, mediawiki

- We have a Mediawiki installation at our company. The original Wiki admin has left. I don't know who has admin rights or the admin username and password.
- I only have user rights on the wiki.
- Goal: To change h2 headers, and the .mw-headline class, to have an underline when the page is printed.
- I've searched Google and MediaWiki help and found I have to make a link to and edit `User:Chuck/Print.css`.
- On one of my Mediawiki pages I've tried to make a link to `[[User:Chuck/Print.css]]`, edited and saved it, but the changes don't take effect.
- I don't know if the variable `$wgAllowUserCss  = true;` is set because I only have Wiki 'user' rights.

What can I do to get the Print.css to work?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two meanings of "admin": the one who is given a role administrator in the MediaWiki website, and the one who controls database and the server. I don't know which one were you referring to (it is also possible that both are the same person).

#### Assuming that $wgAllowUserCss = false;

Then, if you managed to find someone who can access the server, you could ask that person to edit `LocalSettings.php` so that `$wgAllowUserCss = true;`, and now your `User:Chuck/Print.css` will work. Note that it is absolutely impossible to make your `User:Chuck/Print.css` work while `$wgAllowUserCss = false;`.

Otherwise, if you managed to find someone who is given a role administrator, and it is okay to make your change to `Print.css` *systemwide*, you can ask the administrator to edit `MediaWiki:Print.css`. This guarantees to work even when `$wgAllowUserCss = false;`.

Usually there could be more than one user who are given the role administrator. You could see the list of administrators by going to the page Special:ListUsers. For example, here's all administrators in English Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AListUsers&username=&group=sysop&limit=50

Please also note that if you can access the database, you can give a role administrator to a user in the website via the database too.

#### Assuming that $wgAllowUserCss = true;

It is also possible that in fact `$wgAllowUserCss = true;`, but the change doesn't take effect. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache for the solution.

Note: without an admin (in both meanings), pages cannot be deleted, and a lot of system changes cannot be done. Your company wouldn't be able to stay in this state forever. Perhaps you should ask your company to install a new wiki.

Comment: I was referring to getting Wikimedia admin permissions so I could do more on the wiki, as the original Wiki creator/Wiki admin is gone.